# what is the syntax for swift addMenuItem

Tags: swift, watchos-4

I'm a newbie to Swift and cannot work out the syntax to implement Swift addMenuItem.
[The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619515-addmenuitem) says:

> func addMenuItem(with itemIcon: WKMenuItemIcon, 
>   title: String, 
>   action: Selector)

But I can't work out how to apply it.
I want to use a system WKMenuItemIcon like more, with a title like "Add some" and my own action function addMore() like:

```
func addMore() {
//...
}
```

Can some experienced Swifter please show me the syntax for use in Xcode 9.2 and watchOS4 please?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here's the rather obscure solution that works for me:

```
@objc func addMore(){
    print("HERE")
}
```

//elsewhere in code:

```
    addMenuItem(with: WKMenuItemIcon.more, title: "Add More", action: #selector(addMore))
```

Comment: `WKMenuItemIcon` is redundant. `addMenuItem(with: .more, title: "Add More", action: #selector(addMore))`